# Can I impersonate a different user in an HTML web resource? (online 2011/2013)

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I need a user who has access to a lead record, but does not have access to the contact connected with the lead, to be able to view certain contact info. So what I need to be able to do is somehow get around the fact that the user has no access to the underlying contact.

Impersonation seems to fit the bill but all I can find is info about how to impersonate in a plugin and silverlight.

What I'd like to be able to do is somehow impersonate using a HTML web resource on the lead form. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not recommended as it might pose security threats, and that I've never tried it before; you could try using the SOAP endpoint. I believe it wouldn't work with the REST endpoint.

Try using the following SOAP header, where you can put in the GUID of the user you want to impersonate:

```
<soap:Header>
    <CrmAuthenticationToken xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices">
      <AuthenticationType xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/CoreTypes">
        0
      </AuthenticationType>
      <OrganizationName xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/CoreTypes">
        AdventureWorksCycle
      </OrganizationName>
      <CallerId xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/CoreTypes">
        00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
      </CallerId>
    </CrmAuthenticationToken>
  </soap:Header>
```

Check out this link for a possible solution - http://www.datazx.cn/Forums/en-US/cc172c24-0478-4016-9656-ccddffdd7988/action?threadDisplayName=crm4-javascript-impersonation&forum=crmdevelopment

Comment: Thanks. Is it safe to assume that the security risk is only if users within crm were to mess with the javascript? i.e. they could only access the form containing the web resource is they can access crm itself?

Comment: did you try the suggestion? Have the same problem..just wondering if it works?